# is it possible to compile R latex via knitr in a modula way

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave

Is there any way to compile knitr subfiles separately? What I have in mind is something like the package subfiles for latex just in combination with R/knitr/Sweave?
This would be great in case one has two exercises a first exercise with heavy computations and 
don't want to compile the entire exercise always while working and testing the second one.

Answer (score 0):

The `patchDVI` package does this for Sweave.  I imagine it would be possible (maybe even easy) to modify it to do the same for `knitr`.

For example, in Sweave, you define variables in a chunk like so:

```
<<>>=
.TexRoot <- "main.tex"
.SweaveFiles <- c("subfile1.Rnw", "subfile2.Rnw")
@
```

and after `Sweave` is finished running that file, `patchDVI` will check whether the files `subfile1.Rnw` and `subfile2.Rnw` also need to be run, then will run LaTeX on the `main.tex` file once everything is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything difficult, just use the `cache` options. [Lots of details here](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/), but it's probably as simple as specifying `cache = T` in the chunk options of your first exercise.